# Adding a ImageView on top of the MapView

Tags: android

I want to draw free hand drawing on the map view to achieve that I am making my map non-interactive by adding a view on top of fragment and working on MotionEvents and Projection.
For that I have taken a button and on the click of that button i am making my imageview visible so it comes on the foreground and the map view goes in backgound but Its not working as So anybody has any idea where i m getting wrong...I m sharing my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/draw_btn"
        android:text="@string/button" />

     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/draw_view"


    android:layout_below="@+id/draw_btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

     <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
         android:layout_below="@+id/draw_btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MapView` is on top of the `ImageView` because children are layered on top of each other in the order they are added, e.g. the order they appear in the `RelativeLayout` element.  If you move the MapView up, before the ImageView, it will be presented underneath the ImageView.  Perhaps you are thinking that `android:layout_below` refers to the Z-ordering of the views?  It actually controls the vertical position.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    ... button ...

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@+id/draw_btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/draw_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/draw_btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If this doesn't work, there may be more going on with the Window.  For example, the YouTube Player API cuts a hole in the Window so it can detect when other views are presented on top of the video area, immediately stopping playback when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use `LinearLayout` and that **orientation** give as **vertical** and try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/draw_btn"
        android:text="@string/button" />

     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/draw_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

     <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```